# Entity Framework - persisting changes to database only partially

Tags: entity-framework-4, save

Is is possible to select what portion of the Entity Framework entities are persisted back to database?

ObjectContext.SaveChanges() saves everything but if I want to persist only certain items, how to do that?

Comment: Try using multiple contexts

Comment: I'd like to try to avoid using multiple contextes if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to detach the objects you don't want persisted from the ObjectContext. You do this by assigning their EntityState to Detached as follows:

```
context.Products.First().State = EntityState.Detached
```

or

```
context.Detach(Products.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple contexts to keep track of different sets of data:

The following psuedo code should help you.  Cleary there are more ways than just one to do this.

```
using(ObjectContext context1 = new ObjectContext())
{
    using(ObjectContext context2 = new ObjectContext())
    {
        //Do Stuff

        //Now only a portion of your changes are saved to the database
        context2.SaveChanges();

    }
}
```